# date between command in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have one table its contain three fields: id,date and price. id as int, date as Date and price as Float. How can I get one week data from SQL using getdate(). Previous data getting from below attached code using

```
select Date,price from dataupload where MONTH(date)=MONTH(GETDATE()-1)
and day(date)=day(getdate()-1)
```

One week and one month data, how do I check using getdate()

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking - could you edit your question to include some sample data (including some that *shouldn't* be in the final result) and expected results?

Answer (score 1):

For Week

```
  SELECT Date, price
  FROM dataupload
  WHERE Date Between DATEADD(DD,-7,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

For Month

```
  SELECT Date, price
  FROM dataupload
  WHERE Date Between DATEADD(MM,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

did i understand right?

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select Date, price
from dataupload
where date>=dateadd(month,getdate(),-1)
  or date >=dateadd(day,getdate(),-7)
```

But one week and one month data same